# Is there a difference between 事務室 and 事務所?

Tags: word-choice, words, kanji

I want to say that I work in an office. I researched both terms. Shitsu is a room, but I assumed that sho is used more for location. Which term is more appropriate to use?

Comment: What did you find when you "researched both terms"?

Comment: [Maybe this will help](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%BA%8B%E5%8B%99%E5%AE%A4%20%E4%BA%8B%E5%8B%99%E6%89%80). Click on the results to see their respective definitions.

Comment: I found out that both terms are very similar in meaning. I am not clear on the difference between shitsu and sho.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

～室 is for a room, and ～所 is for a facility which usually has more than one room.

If "office" refers to a certain room in an organization, use 事務室. If "office" refers to an entire building, floor or organization, use 事務所.

**EDIT**: The same is true for the translation of "laboratory"; you have to correctly choose between 研究室 and 研究所.